# Blueprint variable is not accepting an actor

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

In my pawn I have an actor component, where I defined this variable

```
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, Category = "Kill")
class ATriggerBox* PressurePlate = nullptr;
```

Then in the blueprint I want to assign a TriggerBox in the scene to this variable:
[image]

So in the "Kill" Category I want to select a TriggerBox to kill the pawn, but every time I open the dropdown and select the TriggerBox, it doesn't select it.

[image]

In the Log I get this message

> Illegal TEXT reference to a private object in external package

Am I doing something wrong?
Do I need to provide more information?

Comment: You want a `TSoftObjectPtr`. A regular pointer to something typically makes it a hard refernce, and the thing referenced is forcefully loaded in. It wouldn't really make sense to allow hard referencing something in a level from a blueprint, since the blueprint could be instantiated in any level.

Answer (score 1):

This approach, when used to connect *instances* of objects in a level, is totally fine. Make sure an instance of your Blueprint and the Trigger Box are in placed in the same level. That way they belong to the same package (the level). Then, select your actor in the scene, and use the details panel to assign the trigger box.

These kind of level-based connections can only be done on *instances of the BP class that are in the same level*. So you have to do it in the details panel when a specific actor is selected in the scene, *not in the editing panel of the Blueprint class* (which edits the default value for *all* instances, independent of which level they’re in.

With that said, it becomes possible to understand why you cannot do this for Classes, aka the Blueprints you edit when you double click an asset. The default value of the variable can’t be assigned to a specific in-level actor reference, because if an instance of the class is created in a different level, the TriggerBox instance you’re referencing wouldn’t exist, as it’s in a different package (different level). That’s what the “private object in external package” refers to.